# Sequences in SQL many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, data-modeling

How do I store a sequence of foreign key values?

Suppose I have:

table1 {id, code}

table2 {id, sequence}

I need table2.sequence to refer to many table1 records to be concatenated in php in their given order.  I want to store arrays, but I'm not thinking SQL.  I could go down the dark route of parsing an array string, or adding an index column to table2 (i.e. have multiple rows per sequence, but then have nightmares changing a sequence), but know there's a better way out there.  Any ideas?

One example:

table1:

1  an

2  example

3  is

4  this

-

table2:

1  ?[4,3,1,2]?

-

'... where table2.id = 1' -> my_concat_function() -> 'thisisanexample'

Comment: Because they aren't foreign keys but rather just a sequence, at least as I read it, perhaps you need to improve the question's language a bit to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use foreign keys, the only option is what you already describe:

> adding an index column to table2 (i.e. have multiple rows per sequence, but then have nightmares changing a sequence)

Another advantage of this is that you can easily check which sequences use a particular word.

Actually, it is not such a nightmare as you think. When you want to modify a sequence, you just need to DELETE all records with a certain ID, and INSERT the records corresponding with the new sequence.

In this case, it is also possible to get the 'sentence' with just SQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM (SELECT table2.id, table1.code
          FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.sequence
          WHERE table2.id = "$table2id"
          ORDER BY table2.index) AS derived
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, deleting the whole record and remaking it ain't so bad; hopefully writing an insert query for sequences will be easy enough.  I completely agree about the extra advantage - I would have rubbed up against that in my case later on!  Also, thanks for the concatenation pointer - saved me a lot of excess code.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain `sequence` column in `table1` itself by referencing it to another column `parent_id` in same table.

Have created a sample structure in sqlfiddle. Hope it works out for you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21932/2/0